# hide a div when click on body and show it when click on a button

Tags: jquery, events, click

i have apply click event on a button and show a div.Also i have apply onclick event on body tag to hide that div.But when i click on button which is also in body then on click function of button call and div show. Same time onclick event of body call and div goes hide.

I want to show div on click on button and hide it when click any other place.

Can anyone help me
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    alert('show');
    $('div').show();
    event.stopPropagation(); // <<<<<<<<
});

$('body').click(function(){
    $('div').hide();
    alert('hide');
})
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MX4xA/

​

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick example. Untested. Can't give much more unless you give some more information.

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="element">Show / hide this</div>
   <div id="button">Click me!</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Click event on body hide the element
    $("body").click(function() {
        $("#element").hide("fast");
    });

    // Click event on button show the element
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#element").show("fast");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

As per [artwl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572504/artwl)'s answer you will want to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("body").click(function(){
        $("#divID").hide();
    });
    $("#btnShow").click(function(event){
        $("#divID").show();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue.

**DEMO:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9s

Whenever you used statement  event.stopPropagation(); in jquery function, then you have to defined event variable as function parameter then it will be considered as event object variable and it works fine.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div id="box">
    Div To be Hide/Show
  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="Show Div"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box{
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background:#55a1dc;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #334499;
  display:none;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Click event on body hide the element
    $("body").click(function(event) {
        $("#box").hide(600);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Click event on button show the element
    $("#btn1").click(function(event) {
        $("#box").show(600);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9s

Answer (score 0):

You can try something below -

```
$('body.aClass').click(function(){
    $('#divId').hide(); 
    $(this).removeClass('aClass'); 
});
$('button').click(function(){ 
    $('#divId').show(); 
    $('body').addClass('aClass'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").click(function(){
        $("#effect").hide();
    });

  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#effect").toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });



   $( "#effect" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on body do something except on specific div

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  // ... clicked on the 'body', but not inside of #menu
});
$('#menu').on('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```